# Undefined/NaN Error with Slider

Tags: javascript, html

I have the slider below:

```js
var rangeValue;
var chanceoflive;
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
  chanceoflive = chanceoflive || 0;

  chanceoflive = rangeValue > 51 ? 2 : 4;
  }
);

function handleClick(){
    alert(chanceoflive);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Height of Your Building
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

<button type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

What's supposed to happen is if the slider is below 51, it will alert 4. If the slider is not below 51, it will alert 2. Although, if the slider is at 50, it alerts undefined or `NaN` or `undefined`. Why does it do it, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm using google chrome

Comment: Your error only comes up if 50 is clicked first without moving the slider.  Looks like it's not initialized

Comment: What do you mean it's not initialized @ Claus

Comment: @NathanChan It means that variable doesn't have any value assigned before you move your slider. So set your variable as `var chanceoflive = 4;` at the beginning and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go now it works

Just needed to initialize chanceoflive

```js
var rangeValue;
var chanceoflive =0;
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
  chanceoflive = chanceoflive || 0;

  chanceoflive = rangeValue > 51 ? 2 : 4;
  }
);

function handleClick(){
    alert(chanceoflive);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Height of Your Building
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

<button type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `chanceoflive` variable uninitialised until `.range-input` is changed.

At least you can write `var chanceoflive = 4;` to correspond to the initial value of the `.range-input`

```js
var rangeValue;
var chanceoflive = 4;
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
  chanceoflive = chanceoflive || 0;

  chanceoflive = rangeValue > 51 ? 2 : 4;
  }
);

function handleClick(){
    alert(chanceoflive);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Height of Your Building
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

<button type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `chanceoflive` calculation out of event in a separated function `getChanceOfLive()` then call it on the both actions `change` and button `click` :

```
var rangeValue;
var chanceoflive;
var inputElement  = document.querySelector('.range-input');
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('.submit');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', getChanceOfLive);
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', getChanceOfLive);

function getChanceOfLive(){
    var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
    chanceoflive = chanceoflive || 0;
    chanceoflive = rangeValue > 51 ? 2 : 4;

    alert(chanceoflive);
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var rangeValue;
var chanceoflive;
var inputElement  = document.querySelector('.range-input');
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('.submit');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', getChanceOfLive);
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', getChanceOfLive);

function getChanceOfLive(){
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
  chanceoflive = chanceoflive || 0;
  chanceoflive = rangeValue > 51 ? 2 : 4;
  
  alert(chanceoflive);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Height of Your Building
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

<button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

**If you want to alert just on submit use :**

```js
var rangeValue;
var chanceoflive;
var inputElement  = document.querySelector('.range-input');
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('.submit');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', getChanceOfLive);
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function(){
   getChanceOfLive();
  
  alert(chanceoflive);
},false);

function getChanceOfLive(){
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
  chanceoflive = chanceoflive || 0;
  chanceoflive = rangeValue > 51 ? 2 : 4;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Height of Your Building
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

<button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
```